# PHP - Check variable or compare string?

Tags: php, string, variables, compare

I wonder which of these excerpts should take less resources, when we want to see if "word" is an element of an array:

Excerpt 1 - Check variable:

```
<?php
function checkWord($word, $elements) {
    $array = array($word => true);
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if (isset($array[$element])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$elements = array('this', 'is', 'an', 'array', 'with', 'a', 'word');
checkWord('word', $elements);
?>
```

Excerpt 2 - Compare string:

```
<?php
function checkWord($word, $elements) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element == $word) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$elements = array('this', 'is', 'an', 'array', 'with', 'a', 'word');
checkWord('word', $elements);
?>
```

I know we could simply use `in_array()`, but that is not the point here.
So, in summary, is a variable check with isset better than comparing strings?

**EDIT** Please understand that *I know* there are better ways of doing this. I am **just** asking which of the ways above is better and takes less resources.

Comment: Shouldn't they be wrapped in functions if they are returning true or false?

Comment: Yeah, this is just a quick code I made. That is not the problem here, but it's ok, I will edit :)

Comment: How about just creating the appropriate array and using in_array?  It will undoubtedly be quicker than what you're proposing.

Comment: in_array should work perfectly for this case. Whats wrong with it??

Comment: Seems you misunderstood my question. Please read my EDIT above.

Comment: Well, in that case why don't you just test it yourself.  Do a million passes one way, and then a million passes the other way.  The shortest run is what you want..

Comment: Ok, I know I can do that, but does that also help me to decide what is the best for CPU? Thank you, pyrony! :)

Comment: I've read this question three times and still don't see how the comments and answer you received don't answer your question. Consider rewording your question to provide more insight or narrowing the scope of your question to exactly what it is you want to know without examples that clearly aren't illustrating your point.

Comment: @Mark, Although it was my fault for speed reading the question the first time, I actually had no trouble understanding that what Nuno wants to know is which of the two methods of iteration over an array is faster and thus less of a resource hog, BESIDES the built-in in_array(). I don't really see any reasons for the downvotes, it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a benchmarking test with a 51000+ unique words list to satisfy your (and mine, to be honest) curiosity. Although not by much, using isset() is indeed faster than comparing strings, with an average of **0.0144901275634765625** seconds for the first method vs **0.0164241790771484375** seconds for the second method, out of 5 tries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I said above we could use that function. That is not the question here.

Comment: I have realized that after I posted, my apologies ! Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for answering the question, and for understanding the purpose of it (I assume you were the only one, to be honest...). Anyway, do these tests help me to decide what is the best for CPU? Thank you once more!

Comment: Glad to be of help ! Actually, this tests only shows that the difference between the methods is negligible, and the fastest method remains `in_array()` @ 0.003899097442626953125 seconds on the mentioned data set. Rather than using alternative methods, I would process the data set in such a way that the built-in method can be used on it, but if for whatever freak reason this is not possible, I would obviously go for the fastest remaining method which in this case is the first one. In the end, it depends mostly on your given data set.

Comment: Ok thank you :) Yeah, I usually rely on built-in functions. Also, I don't really use foreach when I can simply avoid it (because it duplicates the array), so it can also be slowing the tests here :) Anyway, as I was expecting, isset() is better than string compare!